# Gzip response in Flask/Tornado

Tags: python, flask, gzip, tornado, wsgi

I have a simple Flask app running. To serve I use Tornado. The code that starts the server looks like this:

```
# Run the app in server mode
http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(port)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Where *app* is the Flask WSGI app object (`app = Flask(__name__)`).

Now the server responds every request with the entire JSON answer, **is there a (simple) way of returning Gzipped data?** On the Tornado site I found http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/releases/v2.1.0.html?highlight=gzip, so it must be possible with Tornado, but a Flask solution is also great.

Comment: Simple way here - is to use nginx as reverse proxy and gzip data there. It will be much faster, than using python web servers for it.

Comment: This might be true, but I don't want the overhead of running nginx.

Comment: Nginx or other low-level web-server almost always used in front of tornado as reverse proxy. When you gzipping content on python - it's just slow, and strange, because you already have nginx that ate dog on this job. By the way, you can dive into this theme. http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2010/6/14/gzip-compression/#13cd7c9498f74538f48d2a4e557c8148

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just appears weird to set up an nginx only to have gzip compression.

Now I use this http://code.google.com/p/ibkon-wsgi-gzip-middleware/, it's good.

Comment: That GZIP middleware is not WSGI compliant and can cause problems. https://code.google.com/p/ibkon-wsgi-gzip-middleware/issues/detail?id=2 https://code.google.com/p/ibkon-wsgi-gzip-middleware/issues/detail?id=3

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to use Nginx, as Nikolay suggested. It won't add much overhead.

With `tornado.web.Application`, you can just pass `compress_response=True` when initializing the app. Since you're using a Flask, that won't work. You could look at the Tornado source and see what it's doing, but that won't be simple.

Comment: From tornado 4.0 'gzip' changed name to 'compress_response'

Comment: Thanks! this compressed responses by all my API calls. I added this as a key-value pair in the settings json btw. Full list of settings we can use: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.settings

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to reply to a post request then in your tornado.web.RequestHandler derived class, within the "def post(self):"

```
self.set_header("Content-type", 'text/plain') # or whatever you expect
self.set_header("Content-Encoding", 'gzip')
# don't forget to import zlib
gzip_compress = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16)
# response is the string where your response is
content = gzip_compress.compress(response) + gzip_compress.flush()
compressed_content_length = len(content)
self.set_header("Content-Length", compressed_content_length)
self.write(content)
```

Comment: Getting an error at `gzip_compress.compress(response)` part: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Got it to work! `gzip_compress.compress(str.encode(response))`